# Diferença entre .closest() e .find()

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando pegar o valor `.text()` de um elemento no *DOM* pelo nome da sua *class*, ao pesquisar vi que o jQuery disponibiliza pelo menos 2 jeitos de buscar o elemento pela sua *class*:

- O `.closest`, que de acordo com o que entendi da sua [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), pega o primeiro elemento correspondente ao filtro testando o elemento e seus ancestrais...
- O `.find`, que de acordo com o que entendi da sua [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/find/), pega o primeiro elemento correspondente ao filtro testando o elemento e seus descendentes...

Porém o funcionamento dele me parece igual e não consegui destacar uma diferença sólida.

O que eu gostaria é simplesmente um exemplo que exige o uso de um ou outro para fixar suas diferenças e o que difere no modo de funcionamento deles, pois ambos eu sei que fazem a busca no DOM a partir do atributo de um elemento.

Comment: A diferença está na última palavra daquilo que você entendeu de cada um :D Um busca no próprio elemento ou para cima, outro no próprio elemento ou para baixo, por assim dizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Closest

Procura nos seus **ancestrais** por elementos que correspondam ao seletor passado, tal como indicou. Ou seja procura em elementos que **estão para cima**.

Considere a seguinte estrutura:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Agora imagine que se pretende que cada vez que clica num `<a>`, que a cor do `<tr>` no qual ele está inserido se altere. Nesse caso `closest("tr")` dá exatamente o `<tr>` mais próximo para cima no DOM:

```js
$("a").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("cor");
});
```

```css
.cor {
  background-color:cyan;
}

td {
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note que se trocar este `closest` por `find` não irá funcionar pois o `find` apenas procura nos filhos do elemento onde começa a procura. Logo fazendo `$(this).find` no `<a>` irá procurar nos elementos descendentes/filhos de `<a>` em que não haverá nenhum `<tr>`.

Veja como **não funciona**:

```js
$("a").on("click", function(){
  $(this).find("tr").toggleClass("cor");
});
```

```css
.cor {
  background-color:cyan;
}

td {
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Documentação para o `closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

### Find

Este método é utilizado quando precisa de encontrar elementos **descendentes/filhos**, que coincidam com o seletor indicado.

Pegando ainda na estrutura anterior podemos alterar o objetivo para que cada vez que o usuário clique numa linha(`<tr>`) todos os seus `<a>` mudem de cor.

```js
$("tr").on("click", function(){
  $(this).find("a").toggleClass("cor");
});
```

```css
.cor {
  background-color:cyan;
}

td {
  padding:10px;
}

tr {
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Mudei ligeiramente o estilo para se tornar claro que apenas precisa de clicar na area cinza, que é a area abrangida pelo `<tr>`.

Neste caso também não pode trocar `find` por `closest` senão irá o código irá tentar achar um `<a>` que esteja acima do `<tr>` que não há nenhum.

Mesmo exemplo com `closest` para ver que **não funciona**:

```js
$("tr").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest("a").toggleClass("cor");
});
```

```css
.cor {
  background-color:cyan;
}

td {
  padding:10px;
}

tr {
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 2</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Link 3</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Link 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Documentação para o `find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)